# Getting a screenshot of a custom map

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps

Good afternoon. I work with Yandex Map API React (not mobile), my application creates a custom Map. And I had a need to take a screenshot of this Map by pressing one button. How can I do this?

html2canvas doesn't work, because the elements that I have placed on my Map are not displayed.
Also I use custom placemarks, so I do not know how to specify them in the static Yandex map API.